# docker: differences between stopped container vs running container

Tags: docker

I know container is adding a writable layer on the images, but:

What are differences between running container and stopped container in terms of concepts, data preservation and high-level implementation?

Answer (score -1):

Both running and stopped images have a set of metadata that can be accessed via `inspect` and they both have storage and, maybe, logs that can be accessed with `logs`. The only real difference is that a running container has a namespace and a pid. Most commands work on both (except those that are illogical, such as stopping a stopped container or running a running one).

Persistence depends on your volume mappings, but should exist as long as the container exists, no matter its state.

Comment: many resources say that container is a running image, and use a metaphor like food(container) and recipe(image). So does container have a file on disk? and when container is stopped, i assume it's not in memory any more, right? so it saves data in writable layer to this file on disk?

Comment: Any changes you make to the container's file system will be written to disk (unless you configure it not to). The metadata is also saved, but in a different place.